# How to properly set a file path based on a yearly-date basis in R?

Tags: r, date, path, lubridate

I am trying to prevent a future debug for a path file in R, `file_path_minus` corresponds to a file from `10_2020` (october 2020);

For next month the path should has last year and not new year (2021),
being `11_2020` (november 2020) the expected concatenated string and not `11_2021` as the current code does.

I think a scalable function would be excellent as this will be applied to a large amount of paths.

However, how could I approach this?
Is there any function I could use to approach this issue?

Here's the current path coding:

```
# file name #
file_bs_minus<- paste("test", 
                      "_", 
                      lubridate :: month(Sys.Date() %m-% months(2)),
                      "_", 
                      lubridate :: year(Sys.Date()),
                      ".csv",
                      sep= "")
# path file #

path_bs_minus <- paste("data", "bases", file_bs_minus, sep= "/")
```

Comment: It may be better to add the months on the full date instead of extracting

Comment: i.e. `format(Sys.Date() %m-% months(2), "test_%m_%Y.csv")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extracting the `month` and adding `months`, we could do the addition/subtraction on the full `Date` object to avoid the mismatch with `Year` and then `format` it

```
format(Sys.Date() %m-% months(2), "test_%m_%Y.csv")
```

and then we use `file.path` to construct the path

```
file.path("data", "bases", format(Sys.Date() %m-% months(2), "test_%m_%Y.csv"))
#[1] "data/bases/test_10_2020.csv"
```

Testing for the next month

```
format(as.Date("2021-01-05")  %m-% months(2), "test_%m_%Y.csv")
#[1] "test_11_2020.csv"
```